# How to add to a collection while using multi-select properties in Winform PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using PropertyGrid to display data from a de-serialized XML file, and one of the requirement is to add an object to a collection for multiple selected properties like this:

[Selection of multiple properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Htn2n.png)

I'm trying to add another object into the `FieldOption` list like that picture above, but every time I add another item into a collection while selecting multiple properties it gives me an error: `Properties value is not valid/ Collection was of fixed size`

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVjMW.png)

Here is the block of code for the properties that contain the collection I want to add to:

```
 public partial class CompanyConfigurationSiteProfileFieldOptions
    {

        private List<CompanyConfigurationSiteProfileFieldOptionsFieldOption> fieldOptionField;

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("FieldOption", IsNullable = false)]
        /// <remarks/>
        public List<CompanyConfigurationSiteProfileFieldOptionsFieldOption> FieldOption
        {
            get
            {
                return this.fieldOptionField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.fieldOptionField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm still new to Winform and especially PropertyGrid so I haven't tried any solution yet, any help from you guys would be greatly appreciated